# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Parser'

Tags: python, github, attributeerror

This is my final.py file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, './src/')
import lexRule
import parser
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc
import node_file
import genAssembly as ga
import getopt
import pydot

def main(argv):
    to_parse = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"o:f:h",["opt=","file=","help"])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'Usage : ./bin/final.py [options][-f/-h/-o] [string]'
        sys.exit(2)
    parse = parser.Parser()
    optjump = 0
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-o", "--opt"):
            if arg == "1":
                optjump = 1
        elif opt in ("-f", "--file"):
            tree = parse.parse_file(file(arg))
            t = parser.tac.code

            q = []
            if optjump == 1:
                for x in range(0,len(t)-1):
                    if t[x][0] == "goto" and t[x+1][3] == t[x][3]:
                        q.append(x)
                for qw in reversed(q):
                    del t[qw]

                parser.tac.code = t

            old_target = sys.stdout
            ga.generate()

            sys.stdout = open('output.s', 'w')
            ga.generate()

            sys.stdout = old_target


            print("Run ./a.out for execution")
            # os.system("nasm -f elf32 inout.s")
            # os.system("nasm -f elf32 fileio.s")
            os.system("nasm -f elf32 output.s")
            # os.system("nasm -f elf32 val1.s")
            # os.system("nasm -f elf32 next1.s")
            # os.system("nasm -f elf32 append2.s")
            os.system("gcc -m32 output.o ./bin/inout.o ./bin/fileio.o ./bin/val1.o ./bin/next1.o ./bin/append2.o")

        elif opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            _file = open("./README.txt")
            content = _file.read()
            print(content)
        else:
            print 'Usage : ./bin/final.py [options][-f/-h/-o] [string]'
            sys.exit(2)
    if not opts:
        print 'Usage : ./bin/final.py [options][-f/-h/-o] [string]'
        sys.exit(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

when i ran it on cmd this is the error i got.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzGLY.png)
I am using python2 and running these commands:
python bin/final.py -f test/ackermann.java 
python bin/final.py -o 1 -f test/ackermann.java
the project i am trying to run is :https://github.com/abhigarg-iitk/java_compiler

Comment: If you are using the module described here https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html then there simply is no object called Parser available. Maybe you imported the wrong packege?

Comment: @voiDnyx No. i am not using this module...i have my own python file in the project in my src folder

Comment: I guess since you named your module the same as the standard library parser module you will have to explicitly import your own module by using the `from ... import ...` syntax. E.g. `from src import parser`

Comment: @voiDnyx this worked.Thanks. i also had to insert __init__.py file in my src folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using your own parser module (named the same as the standard library) located in another location than the standard library packages you need to import it using the `from ... import ...` syntax and an `__init.py__` file in your parser package directory.

For further reading you can have a look at the python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html